# Usar diferentes policies para distintos paneles en FilamentPHP

Tags: php, laravel, filamentphp, policies

Tengo en desarrollo un proyecto saas donde utilizo 3 paneles, entre ellos Panel de Admin, Companies y Alumnos, ya cree mi sistema de roles y permisos, con las politicas necesarias, las aplique a los usuarios del panel companies, todo hasta ahi va perfecto, pero al momento de ingresar al panel de Admin no me deja ya que al estar utilizando el mismo modelo me arroja problemas de configuración. Intente solucionar este problema creando otra politica de acceso exclusivamente para el panel de Admin, pero no me funciona.

tengo mi politica creada de esta forma:

1.-Policies que utilizo y funciona perfecto en el Panel de Companies

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;

class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        return $user->hasRole('Administrador');
    }

}
```

2.- Policies creada para el Panel de Admin

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;

class AdminPanelPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        // Permitir acceso a todos los usuarios para el panel de administración
        return true;
    }
}
```

3 Panel de Admin:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Filament;


use Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Pages;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

use App\Policies\AdminPanelPolicy; // Importa la nueva política

class SuperadminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->id('superadmin')
            ->path('admin')
            ->colors([
                'primary' => Color::Green,
            ])
            ->login()
            ->passwordReset()
            ->authGuard('web')
            ->maxContentWidth('full')
            ->sidebarCollapsibleOnDesktop()
            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Superadmin/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Superadmin\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Superadmin/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Superadmin\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                Pages\Dashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Superadmin/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Superadmin\\Widgets')
            ->widgets([
                Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
                //Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class,
            ])
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
            ])
            ->authMiddleware([
                Authenticate::class,
                'can:viewAny,' . AdminPanelPolicy::class, // Asociar la política al middleware de autorización
            ]);
    }
}
```

En el panel de admin dentro del authMiddleWare agrege el 'can:viewAny' pero no funciona, me sigue arrojando que el policies que esta utilizandose es el UserPolicy.

```
App\Policies\UserPolicy::viewAny(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type App\Models\User, App\Models\Admin given, called in C:\Users\mypc\Documents\my-multitenancy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 811
```

esto lo tome como ejemplo de lo que me sugiere Chatpgt, pero no me resulta.

Comment: pero si cambias de usuario para entrar a la de admin ... no se supone que debes destruir la politicas anteriores y cargar las nuevas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto esto finalmente utilizando instanceOf

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(Model $user): bool
    {
        if($user instanceof Admin) {
            return true;
        }else if($user instanceof User){
            return $user->hasRole('Administrador');
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

esto significa que si el usuario logeado es del modelo Admin retorna true, de lo contrario si es del Modelo User retornara el role que tiene o no!